# Python multiple repeat Error

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to determine whether a term appears in a string.
Before and after the term must appear a space, and a standard suffix is also allowed.
Example:

```
term: google
string: "I love google!!! "
result: found

term: dog
string: "I love dogs "
result: found
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
regexPart1 = "\s"
regexPart2 = "(?:s|'s|!+|,|.|;|:|\(|\)|\"|\?+)?\s"  
p = re.compile(regexPart1 + term + regexPart2 , re.IGNORECASE)
```

and get the error:

```
raise error("multiple repeat")
sre_constants.error: multiple repeat
```

**Update**
Real code that fails:

```
term = 'lg incite" OR author:"http++www.dealitem.com" OR "for sale'
regexPart1 = r"\s"
regexPart2 = r"(?:s|'s|!+|,|.|;|:|\(|\)|\"|\?+)?\s" 
p = re.compile(regexPart1 + term + regexPart2 , re.IGNORECASE)
```

On the other hand, the following `term` passes smoothly (`+` instead of `++`)

```
term = 'lg incite" OR author:"http+www.dealitem.com" OR "for sale'
```

Comment: http://cthedot.de/retest/, http://re-try.appspot.com/

Comment: I don't get this error with your code and your input on either 2.7 or 3.3. Can you give us an actual reproducible test case?

Comment: As a side note, you really should be using raw strings with regexps. You get lucky here because none of your backslashes happen to be part of Python escape sequences, but you should never rely on that.

Comment: I'm using RegexBuddy and the regex apparently works

Comment: Actually, wait, no you don't get lucky…

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The problem is that, in a non-raw string, `\"` is `"`.

You get lucky with all of your other unescaped backslashes—`\s` is the same as `\\s`, not `s`; `\(` is the same as `\\(`, not `(`, and so on. But you should never rely on getting lucky, or assuming that you know the whole list of Python escape sequences by heart.

Either print out your string and escape the backslashes that get lost (bad), escape *all* of your backslashes (OK), or just use raw strings in the first place (best).

---

That being said, your regexp as posted won't match some expressions that it should, but it will never raise that `"multiple repeat"` error. Clearly, your actual code is different from the code you've shown us, and it's impossible to debug code we can't see.

---

Now that you've shown a real reproducible test case, that's a *separate* problem.

You're searching for terms that may have special regexp characters in them, like this:

```
term = 'lg incite" OR author:"http++www.dealitem.com" OR "for sale'
```

That `p++` in the middle of a regexp means "1 or more of 1 or more of the letter p" (in the others, the same as "1 or more of the letter p") in some regexp languages, "always fail" in others, and "raise an exception" in others. Python's `re` falls into the last group. In fact, you can test this in isolation:

```
>>> re.compile('p++')
error: multiple repeat
```

If you want to put random strings into a regexp, you need to call [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) on them.

---

One more problem (thanks to Ωmega):

`.` in a regexp means "any character". So, `,|.|;|:"` (I've just extracted a short fragment of your longer alternation chain) means "a comma, or any character, or a semicolon, or a colon"… which is the same as "any character". You probably wanted to escape the `.`.

---

Putting all three fixes together:

```
term = 'lg incite" OR author:"http++www.dealitem.com" OR "for sale'
regexPart1 = r"\s"
regexPart2 = r"(?:s|'s|!+|,|\.|;|:|\(|\)|\"|\?+)?\s"  
p = re.compile(regexPart1 + re.escape(term) + regexPart2 , re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

As Ωmega also pointed out in a comment, you don't need to use a chain of alternations if they're all one character long; a character class will do just as well, more concisely and  more readably.

And I'm sure there are other ways this could be improved.

Comment: That's a whole different problem. Let me edit my answer to explain.

Comment: `r"(?:'?s|!+|[,.;:\(\)\"]|\?+)?\s"`

Comment: @Ωmega: Nice catch of a third bug in the original code (in your edit). Using `.` in an alternation is kind of silly, isn't it… But we should probably _explain_ the error, rather than just fix it without even telling the OP it was fixed.

Comment: I was getting the same error with this regex pattern - `^('GSP|BG')[-]*[0-9]*+$`. Removed the second `*` (before the `+`) and changed it to `^('GSP|BG')[-]*[0-9]+$` - problem solved!

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. That was very useful!

Answer (score 10):

The other answer is great, but I would like to point out that using regular expressions to find strings in other strings is not the best way to go about it.  In python simply write:

```py
if term in string:
    # do whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

A general solution to "multiple repeat" is using re.escape to match the literal pattern.
Example:

```
>>>> re.compile(re.escape("c++"))
re.compile('c\\+\\+')
```

However if you want to match a literal word with space before and after try out this example:

```
>>>> re.findall(rf"\s{re.escape('c++')}\s", "i love c++ you c++")
[' c++ ']
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that your arguments are in the correct order!

I was trying to run a regular expression on some html code. I kept getting the multiple repeat error, even with very simple patterns of just a few letters.

Turns out I had the pattern and the html mixed up. I tried `re.findall(html, pattern)` instead of `re.findall(pattern, html)`.

Comment: I feel really stupid right now

Answer (score 1):

i have an example_str = "i love you c++" when using regex get error multiple repeat Error. The error I'm getting here is because the string contains "++" which is equivalent to the special characters used in the regex. my fix was to use re.escape(example_str ), here is my code.

```
example_str = "i love you c++" 

regex_word = re.search(rf'\b{re.escape(word_filter)}\b', word_en)
```

Comment: Shorter version:


    regex_word = re.search(re.escape(word_filter), word_en)